# Convert StackTrace to SByte[] format

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stack-trace

.NET's exceptions store the stack trace in `SByte[]` format (as well as string). It's fairly simple to get the current stack trace in string format at any time during execution by invoking `(new StackTrace()).ToString()` or `Environment.StackTrace`, however, it's not immediately clear (to me at least) how to get the current stack trace in `SByte[]` format, without reading it from an exception.

**Disclaimer:** I understand that this is supposed to be used by the framework, but I'm still interested in understanding this, call it academic curiosity.

Comment: you could use reflection if its a private field of `Exception`

Comment: I'm not asking how to read the stacktrace of an existing exception, I'm asking how to convert a StackTrace object into sbyte[] (no exception involved)